# How to get the min/max time in continuous times and the count of times in this range?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Date:

```
2015-04-01 12:00
2015-04-01 11:00
2015-04-01 10:
2015-04-01 09:
2015-04-01 08:00 // <---
2015-04-01 05:00
2015-04-01 04:00
2015-04-01 03:00
2015-04-01 02:00
2015-04-01 01:00 // <---
2015-03-31 22:00
2015-03-31 21:00
2015-03-31 20:00
2015-03-31 19:00 // <---
```

I want to get this result:

```
MaxTime          | MinTime          | Count
2015-04-01 12:00 | 2015-04-01 08:00 | 5
2015-04-01 05:00 | 2015-04-01 01:00 | 5
2015-03-31 22:00 | 2015-03-31 19:00 | 4
```

Comment: What have you tried to get that result?

Comment: Is the difference between the times always exactly 1 hour?

Comment: yes,always exactly 1 hour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query

```
select
    max(dateColumn), min(dateColumn), count(dateColumn)
from (
    select 
        dateColumn, datepart(dayofyear, dateColumn)*24 + datepart(hh, dateColumn) - row_number() over (order by dateColumn) grp
    from
        MyTable
) t
group by grp
```

Comment: Great idea! But this will fail for sequential times in different years (12/31->01/01). Instad of `DAYOFYEAR` and `DATEPART`, you could use `DATEDIFF(HOUR,@MINDAT,dateColum)` with `@MINDAT=CONVERT(DATETIME,0)`.

Comment: Great idea! 
Thank you very much for your reply, perfect~！

Answer (score 0):

Sample Data

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #Temp

;With cte(Dates)
AS
(
SELECT '2015-04-01 12:00' UNION ALL
SELECT '2015-04-01 11:00' UNION ALL
SELECT '2015-04-01 10:00' UNION ALL
SELECT '2015-04-01 09:00' UNION ALL
SELECT '2015-04-01 08:00' UNION ALL
SELECT '2015-04-01 05:00' UNION ALL
SELECT '2015-04-01 04:00' UNION ALL
SELECT '2015-04-01 03:00' UNION ALL
SELECT '2015-04-01 02:00' UNION ALL
SELECT '2015-04-01 01:00' UNION ALL
SELECT '2015-03-31 22:00' UNION ALL
SELECT '2015-03-31 21:00' UNION ALL
SELECT '2015-03-31 20:00' UNION ALL
SELECT '2015-03-31 19:00' 
)
SELECT * INTO #Temp FROM cte     
SELECT * FROM   #Temp
```

Your Expected Result script using Row_number()Over() Function

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        MAX(Dates)OVER(PArtition by BatchSeq Order by (SELECT 1)) AS MaxTime
       ,MIN(Dates)OVER(PArtition by BatchSeq Order by (SELECT 1)) AS MinTime
       ,COUNT(Dates)OVER(PArtition by BatchSeq Order by (SELECT 1)) As [Count]
FROM
(
SELECT Dates  ,  ((ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1))-1)/5+1) AS BatchSeq  FROM
#Temp
)dt
ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

Your Expected Result script using Group by() Function

```
SELECT 
        MAX(Dates)   AS MaxTime
       ,MIN(Dates)  AS MinTime
       ,COUNT(Dates) As [Count]
FROM
(
SELECT Dates ,((ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1))-1)/5+1) AS BatchSeq  FROM
#Temp
)dt
GROUP BY BatchSeq
ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

Result

```
 MaxTime                MinTime         Count
  --------------------------------------------
  2015-04-01 12:00  2015-04-01 08:00    5
  2015-04-01 05:00  2015-04-01 01:00    5
  2015-03-31 22:00  2015-03-31 19:00    4
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply，but …